# I keep getting Object.parseHttpRespMessage when uploading to google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I am using a cloud function to unpack a file and then re-upload it to GCS -I keep getting the following error. Has anyone encountered this before?

```
     ApiError: Not Found
at Object.parseHttpRespMessage (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:156:33)
```

This is the code used to upload -

```
else {
                    console.log(`Decompressed ${tempLocalFile}`);
                    fs.recurse(tempLocalDir, "**/*", function(filepath, relative, filename) {
                        if (!filename) return; // ignore dirs
                        console.log(filepath + ":" + relative + ":" + filename);
                        return bucket.upload(filepath, {
                            destination: "html/" + relative,
                            metadata: {}
                        })
                    });
```

Comment: Did you ever work this out? I'm getting the same error when trying to delete a file in Storage.